# Equivalent of this: echo 'test content' | git hash-object -w --stdin

Tags: git, bash, powershell

I'm reading the [Git Book on Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), which has the following command:

```
echo 'test content' | git hash-object -w --stdin
```

- `echo` is a bash command that, in this case, writes the string to standard output
- `--stdin` is a git option that reads from standard input

What is the equivalent command in PowerShell? My best guess is just to use the exact same command, which appears to work in PowerShell the same way.

```
 echo "test content" | git hash-object -w --stdin
```

Comment: if that gives you a SHA, and you `git cat-file -p SHA` and it spews out "test content" then you are set.

Comment: @AndrewC Perfect. Thank you for the code to test. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI `echo` is an alias for `Write-Output` which writes output to the Output stream. When piping to executables that output is written to stdout, which is received by stdin on the git side.